# What is the difference between Windows Azure SDK 1.7 and SDK 1.8?

Tags: azure

I am working on windows Azure SDK1.8. I haven't worked on SDK1.7. 
Anybody knows what's the difference between them. Please share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the release notes for each release here to compare what has changed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683673.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think the two biggest things are:

- Ability to use .NET 4.5 and Windows Server 2012
- Use server explorer to connect to storage account

as JuneT suggested you can always get the full list at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683673.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know I just recently had to install this in order to successfully use the [Azure Plugin to Eclipse for Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690946.aspx).